# load jquery library in grails 2 is failing?

Tags: grails, grails-2.2

I was following the manual

https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.2.0/guide/single.html#ajax

there it says to put the following tag in head section

```
<g:javascript library="jquery" />
```

I created a sample application and a test controller called HomeController. I created index page and put the above tag in the head. When i load the page it throws the following error.

[image]

I am finding the error difficult to comprehend. I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: if your `index` page is not using any layout then make sure you have `<r:layoutResources/>` at the end of your head and body. And if using layout also make sure you have `<r:layoutResources/>` in your layout gsp (same end of head and body)

Comment: thanks! <meta name="layout" content="main"/> was missing in the index file. Now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `index` page is not using any `layout` then make sure you have `<r:layoutResources/>` at the end of your head and body.

And if using layout, then make sure you have `<r:layoutResources/>` in your layout gsp (at the end of head and body).